# Reordering an integer column in a data frame gives incorrect order

Tags: r

I am retrieving a list of files in my folder and I want to create a data frame. The files in the folder all contain the names "1.png", "2.png", etc. I want to create a data frame with a column named "Number" and a column named "Extension" and reorder the data frame based on the numerical values of the "Number" column.

I start by extracting the list of files into a data frame:

```
MyList <- data.frame(Number = list.files(path), Extension = NA)
```

Which ends up looking like this:

```
   Number Extension
1   1.png        NA
2  10.png        NA
3  11.png        NA
4  12.png        NA
5  13.png        NA
```

And so on... Next I split the Numbers based on the dots:

```
MyList$Extension <- lapply(strsplit(MyList$Number, "\\."), "[", 2)
MyList$Number <- lapply(strsplit(MyList$Number, "\\."), "[", 1)
```

Which gives me:

```
 Number Extension
1     1       png
2    10       png
3    11       png
4    12       png
5    13       png
```

So far so good... Now all I need is to reorder the data frame in ascending order based on the column "Number":

```
MyList$Number <- order(as.numeric(MyList$Number), decreasing = FALSE)
```

And the result:

```
 Number Extension
1     1       png
2    22       png
3    33       png
4    34       png
5    35       png
```

For some reason that didn't work? I expected it to be ordered like this:

```
 Number Extension
1     1       png
2     2       png
3     3       png
4     4       png
5     5       png
```

etc... The column "Number" is of class integer:

```
> class(MyList$Number)
[1] "integer"
```

What went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we need the actual values ordered, use the index from the `order` the dataset using the index as row index instead of assigning the index as the column 'Number'

```
MyList <- MyList[order(as.numeric(MyList$Number), decreasing = FALSE),]
```